# Extract all numbers in a string that do not preceed with a specific word in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to count the occurrences of numbers of all formats with certain exceptions on the words that precede the numbers.

I have a string "2% about 2% 2 about 2" that I name as test. I want to count the occurrence of all types of number formats in the string without a preceding "about".

I used the code:

```
str_count(test, "^(?!about\\s)(\\+?)(\\.?)\\d+")
```

The output is 1 whereas I expect the answer to be 2 (both "2%" at the beginning and "2" after the second occurrence of 2%).

Comment: You can try `str_count(test2, "(?<!\\babout\\s{1,100})\\d*\\.?\\d+")`. ICU regex lookbehinds support constrained-width patterns.

Comment: If I use this code for the strings "about 10.5", "about 11",
           "about 1,000", "about .05", "about .05%", "about +2",
           "about +.3", "about +0.3", each one of them gives the answer as 1. Why so?

Comment: Because it just matches the next best digits where the condition succeeds. If there is always space (or start) before the digit and `about` followed by one space, try [`(?<!\S)(?<!about\s)\+?\.?\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/4OoOrr/1) (add escapes).

Comment: Does [this regex and R code](https://ideone.com/e2wFnj) work for you (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccpZX3/2))?

Comment: @bobblebubble: Your code works for me really well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a non-stringr solution because with base R regex functions, you can use a PCRE regex that can match and skip strings that you do not want, and then match what you need.

The pattern can look like

```
\babout\s+([-+]?(?:\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+))\b(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccpZX3/2). The [R code](https://ideone.com/e2wFnj):

```r
pattern <- "\\babout\\s+([-+]?(?:\\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d+)?|\\.\\d+))\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)"
# 16 strings, 8 good and 8 bad
vec <- c("about 10.5","about 11","about 1,000","about .05","about .05%","about +2","about +.3","about +0.3","t 10.5","t 11","t 1,000","t .05","t .05%","t +2","t +.3","t +0.3")
res <- grepl(pattern, vec, perl=TRUE) # Gets matching items
length(res[res==TRUE])                # Counts the TRUE only items
```

The output is

```
[1] 8
```

*Pattern details*

- `\b` - word boundary
- `about` - an `about` word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([-+]?(?:\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+))` - Group 1:

  - `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
  - `(?:\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)` - either of

    - `\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?` - one to three digits, then zero or more repetitions of a `.` or `,` and then three digits, and then an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits
    - `|` - or
    - `\.\d+` - a dot and then one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - the text matched is discarded and the engine starts looking for another match from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `(?1)` - the Group 1 pattern.